# Unregister event handler to prevent multiple callback in c# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Every time I call the method subscribe event handler. So it get called multiple times as I don't unsubscribe event handler. How do properly unsubscribe event handler to prevent multiple callback of **onComplete**?

```
public void DoTheAction(Action<bool> onComplete = null) {
        if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded()) {
            rewardBasedVideo.Show();
            rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += (sender, args) => {
                onComplete(true);
            };
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to think about refactoring your code so you don't have this problem but this is how you can achieve what you are asking.

```
public void DoTheAction(Action<bool> onComplete = null)
    {
        if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
        {
            rewardBasedVideo.Show();
            rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded -= HandleOnAdRewarded;
            rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleOnAdRewarded;    
        }
    }

    private void HandleOnAdRewarded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        onComplete(true);
    }
```

Comment: The name "onComplete" does not exist in current context?

Comment: Oh my bad. I think you'll need to refactor so that ```onComplete``` can be accessed within ```HandleOnAdRewarded```.

Comment: @AsimKrishnaDas no need to be rude. The answer is to use a method for your event handler rather than an anonymous delegate. You've not provided enough of your code for someone to be able to refactor it for you. So now you need to figure out how you can make that solution work in your context.

Comment: Thank you boss for your suggestion. As I am not that expert in c# to call onComplete from another method HandleOnAdRewarded. Could you please give me a link better understand about that? Highly appreciate if kindly edit your answer for me. Thank you again.